# selenium screenshots not saving specified directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have my selenium test set up to take screenshots, but they are not saving to the directory which I have specified. Can anybody show me what I am missing?

Here is how I am configuring the screenshots in the test:

```
function writeScreenshot(data, name) {
      var fs = require('fs');
      name = name || 'ss.png';
      var screenshotPath = mkdirp(configuration.readSettings('screenshotDirectory') + fileNameURL + "/", function(err){});
      fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath + name, data, 'base64');
};
```

and then I take the screenshot:

```
driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
        var screenshotFile = os + '_' + osVersion + '_' + browser + '_' + browserVersion + '.png';
        writeScreenshot(data, screenshotFile);
});
```

The screenshots end up being saved instead in the projects root directory and with the file name preceded by 'undefined'. (ex. `undefinedWindows_8_chrome_46.png`)
It does, however, create the folders shown here: `var screenshotPath = mkdirp(configuration.readSettings('screenshotDirectory') + fileNameURL + "/", function(err){});`

So why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mkdirp()` is an async method. That is why you pass a `callback`. You will need to change your code to something like the following:

```
function writeScreenshot(data, name) {
      var fs = require('fs');
      name = name || 'ss.png';
      var screenshotPath = configuration.readSettings('screenshotDirectory') + fileNameURL + "/";
      mkdirp(screenshotPath, function(err){
          if (err) {
               // something else happened while creating the dir. You decide what to do
               return;
          }
          // Otherwise (if dir was created)
          fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath + name, data, 'base64');
      });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

[`mkdirp()` function](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp#mkdirpdir-opts-cb) is asynchronous - *it creates a directory and returns nothing* - this is why you having that leading `undefined` in the filename.

Save the file *in the callback*:

```
var screenshotPath = configuration.readSettings('screenshotDirectory') + fileNameURL + "/";
mkdirp(screenshotPath, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath + name, data, 'base64');
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Or, [synchronously](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp#mkdirpsyncdir-opts) create the directory and write to it this way:

```
var screenshotPath = configuration.readSettings('screenshotDirectory') + fileNameURL + "/";
if (mkdirp.sync(screenshotPath)) {
    fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath + name, data, 'base64');
}
```

Comment: the asynchronous method works well, thank you. But the synchronous method does not save the files to the newly made directory, and does not save them to the root directory like it was doing originally. Not sure where they are being saved